# How to set background color for dropdown arrow spinner programatically

Tags: android

I developed a library project which handle all process from application project. 
In Main Activity of library project, I made an Alert Dialog and adding an spinner's dropdown list

```
spinner = new Spinner(this);
spinner.setLayoutParams(snLayoutParam);

ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,  Arrays.asList(str)); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

when I set background color for spinner by `spinner.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE)` it effect to arrow selector icon and it did not appear anymore.

Because library project can not use android resource (.xml, drawable, layout...), so i can not applied designed xml style for it

So please help me: how to set color for arrow icon

Comment: Finally my approach is design a StateListDrawable and set it as background for Spinner and it works well, Thanks for your time